# How to Handle new line in cakePHP getting data from views

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am working on CakePHP, I am getting the data from the textarea to the controller and 
  stored it into DB,Retriving the data from DB and showing on the view,It is Fine.I faced a
  Problem when i am giving the data in new lines, the data is stored successfully coming to 
  the view part it is showing syntax error,why because in jQuery i am trying to display the 
  textarea value using .val('sometext') function.For solving my problem iam using addslashes,
  addcslashes but there is no use,please specify the better way for handling new lines.

My Code in ctp :

```
$('#description').val('<?php echo $file['description'];?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make sure that this is a good approach... If it is then just use `json_encode()`:

```
$('#description').val('<?php echo json_encode($file['description']);?>');
```